# SSH authentication failed, please provide another key- Acquia

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

Team,

I'm trying to Clone my Cloud website and use it in Dev desktop.

I have generated 4096 keygen and add public key in Acquia Cloud.

I am using Latest Acquia Dev Desktop on Windows 10.

I am getting below error-

> Blockquote
>   SSH authentication failed, please provide another key- Acquia
>   Blockquote

Anyone facing similar issue?

Thanks,
SS

Comment: Sometimes new keys can take a while to propagate in Acquia's system. Sometimes it can take a couple of hours before the key is recognized. How long has this been happening? Otherwise, you should just file a ticket with Acquia Support for their assistance.

Comment: I am new user to Drupal, I have install Acquia Dev Desktop yest onl
y.

Comment: Do i have to wait after creation?

Comment: I have the same issue did not find any solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too with Dev Desktop 2.
It was my first time trying to pull an Acquia cloud site to local.
I generated a key, added my public key to my Acquia profile, but still kept getting Authentication errors.

What fixed it for me was...
SSH into the server (little square next to the SSH path in dev desktop), then just close it.
I was then able to pull the cloud site to my local machine.

Comment: I can concur that this is a correct approach and solved my problem. On a Mac, depending on what type of permissions you have for your account, clicking on this black terminal window will cause the terminal window to pop up and then a security box that you have to click "allow." Once that's done, again depending on permissions, you may be prompted again that Dev Desktop wants to make changes and you must supply the user name and password for the cloning process to start.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue resolved by using https://docs.acquia.com/dev-desktop/troubleshooting

SSH key error

If, when you synchronize a website between Acquia Dev Desktop and Acquia Cloud, you experience an SSH key error, you may be able to resolve it by doing the following:

- In Acquia Dev Desktop, click Acquia Dev Desktop > Preferences.
- On the Settings > General tab, click Remove local websites cloned from Acquia Cloud, and then click OK.
- Click the + button and select Add Acquia Cloud websites.

Comment: this is the equivalent of logging out and logging back in. but sadly didnt work for me